# ios8 Core Data iCloud Today Widget not synchronizing

Tags: core-data, ios8

I have been unsuccessful in getting core data to work on an app and today widget on my device.

```
let url  = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.mygroup.name").URLByAppendingPathComponent("fileName.sqllite")
var error: NSError? = nil 
let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true,NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:"SharedContainerName"
        ]        
let s = coordinator?.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: options
            , error: &error)
```

I have added a group container that I use for the URL of the stores. I have noticed on the simulators that my persistent coordinator points to the same sqllite file

(URL: file:///Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6Cxxxxxx/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/E65xxxxxx/fileName.sqllite))

This seems to work fine on the simulator and I can store data in my main app and fetch it in today widget. When I run the code on my device the files are at different locations and the databases are not synchronized (no data on the today widget).

My Main App

(URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/2CCXXX/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~F74XXX/SharedContainerName/**0E8XXXX**/store/fileName.sqllite))

Today Widget

(URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/2CCXXX/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~F74XXX/SharedContainerName/**2FBYYYY**/store/fileName.sqllite))

I am assuming this should be fine as they should be synchronized by iCloud. The widget runs fine, however it has no data (like it has not been synchronized). Now debugging this has been tricky as I am unable to get console output while running the today widget. When I run the widget from Xcode as opposed to attaching to the running process (The only way I can get any output on the console) I receive an error core data iCloud: Error: initial sync notification returned an error BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 12. I receive no notifications. Maybe iCloud and Core Data do not work at this time with a today widget? The core data code in my app and extension are identical so I do not think I have a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Apple Developer Forum message](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1050891#1050891) from an Apple employee:

> None of iCloud is accessible from within an Extension in iOS 8.0

and he adds in another message:

> Document syncing, I should clarify, or anything which requires file coordination.  I'm not sure about KVS or CloudKit

The recommendation is to expose the application state to extensions using some other method (plist, separate files, etc), which is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: Thanks! I am so glad I gave up on trying to get it to work. I have used a work around if anyone is interested (well maybe a hack). From my main app I store the full URL of the iCloud store (when enabled) in the user defaults using a group container. I then check if it exists in my extension. If it is I open it read only as if it were a non icloud store (no NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey) otherwise fallback to a non iCloud store. The extension only needs to read data so this works for me. If the main app updates the database I just notify the extension through userdefaults.

Comment: That's pretty clever. I'm a little surprised that the extension has access to the ubiquity container. I chickened out and just write out a plist of the subset of data I needed to display in the extension.

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem but while testing I'm able to sent new data to other device from iOS today widget both for key-value store and core data (only tested with the OS X counterpart for my iOS app)